# How do we know if distant stars we see by their light are real objects?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, stars

Is there a way to be sure if they are not just light, but real objects?

Comment: What produces "just light"?

Comment: is the sun real? it is distant enough. we see the spectral lines from known atoms and  their  motions agree with Newton's laws to first order. If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck it is a duck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philosophy rather than physics.

Answer (score 1):

The light we see from the stars is not "just light". The spectrum contains the absorption and emission lines of many of the elements in the star. So it is not just a black body radiator like most light bulbs - we can see what they are made of.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question relates to the *gravitational lensing*. The problem of locating a body (finding its actual position) given only its apparent location (as seen by some one on Earth -by considering their light has travelled in a straight line only) is studied only recently (though the problem existed for almost a century till now).

As far as I have studied so far, this problem is addressed only experimentally (like finding a stars location during a solar eclipse). You can always look up [this page on gravitational lensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main) for more information